# width 100% buttons inside div

Tags: html, css, cordova

I'm making a Phonegap app, for that i am using html, css and jquery mobile css framework.
I'm trying to make a menu with 3 buttons that glued to each other and centered. I want them to occupy the entire parent div width.
I tried to set some properties but it doesn't work..

Here is the code :

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent ui-first-child">1</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent">2</a>
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent ui-last-child">3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to set a *width 100%* at parent's div and *width:auto* to **.ui-controlgroup-controls** but it doesn't fit all width.

Actual css :

```
.ui-controlgroup {
width: 100% !important;
}
.ui-controlgroup, fieldset.ui-controlgroup {
padding: 0;
margin: .5em 0;
```

And

```
.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
width: inherit !important;
}
```

I want to set this width in % to be responsive on small smartphones.

Thanks!

Comment: did you add the width 100% to .ui-controlgroup-controls, inline css ?

Comment: show us your css please

Comment: I did width 100% to **.ui-controlgroup** and width auto to **.ui-controlgroup-controls**

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Nop, only jquery mobile

Comment: [jquery mobile grid system](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/content/content-grids.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [**Jquery mobile grid system**.](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.2/docs/content/content-grids.html) since you are using already jQuery mobile, this will make a nice centered 3 buttons. to the ui-controlgroup-controls go to full width use this css rule.

```
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
    display: inline !important;
    /* or you can choose to */
    /* display: block !important; */
    /* there are other options for display that work, not inline-block */
}
```

The markup will look like this. Notice the ui-grid-b and the ui-block-a, ui-bloc-b and ui-block-c.

```
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ui-grid-b">
      <div class="ui-block-a">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent ui-first-child">1</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-b">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent">2</a>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-block-c">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent ui-last-child">3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Finally a [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/T2f0ocrn32tz4V1d3rjW?p=preview).

**Edit**
if you only whant this to apply to the controlgroup-horizontal.

```
.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls{
  display: inline !important;
}
```

or else you can write your own rule and apply it to the markup class

Comment: Glad that i could help. :)

Answer (score 2):

`width: auto` sizes the div to the width of the text. If you want everything to be full width, set the parent to `width: 100%` and the element (and its children?) to `width: 100%` or `width: inherit`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to do that (cf edited post) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve / isn't working about it?

Answer (score 2):

parent element is `<div>`, it's automatically is 100% width because it's default property is `display: block;`, but tag `<a>` default property is `display: inline;`

You should just make tag `<a>` `display: inline-block;` and say them to take 33% of width.

Important: between elements who are display: inline-block; should not be spaces or line breaks, otherwise there will bee little spaces like between words.

```css
.ui-controlgroup {
width: 100% !important;
}
.ui-controlgroup, fieldset.ui-controlgroup {
padding: 0;
margin: .5em 0;
}

.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.ui-controlgroup-controls {
  width: inherit !important;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-btn-transparent {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33%;
  
  text-align: center;
  background: red;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal ui-corner-all">
    <div class="ui-controlgroup-controls ">
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent ui-first-child">1</a><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent">2</a><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-transparent ui-last-child">3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I don't want to superimpose them but put them next to each other

Comment: It worked too but I'll use jquery mobile grid system like Jose Rocha said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
100%;
```

to:

```
100vh;
```

I hope it works